# Kernel Panic when killing Node js - Help me figure it out

Tags: macos, bash, node.js, v8

I am experiencing kernel panics when I kill node js under certain circumstances such as when it is stuck in an infinite loop (always) or when it is a stopped job under Bash (sometimes).

EDIT:  My code isn't doing anything network related.  I'm running a modified CoffeeScript repl.

I don't expect to be able to get a direct answer since it is a rather complicated problem and may be a bug in node, v8, or OS X for all I know at the moment.

However, I am at least somewhat familiar with all the technical aspects required to find it so I think with the right clues I could narrow it down, prevent it, and send a bug report to the appropriate people.

Feel free to have me investigate anything, up to and include using programs such as SIMBL and Application Enhancer if need be.

Here is the error report from the last kernel panic:
http://pastie.org/3043592

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure, but my suspicions would lie first with the following kernel extensions:

1. `at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch`. Little Snitch messes with the network stack in some pretty major ways, so it seems likely that it might have something to do with your crashes (assuming that your node.js app is using sockets).
2. `com.cisco.nke.ipsec`. It also has to do with networking, so I'm also suspicious. Less so, though, because it (theoretically...) should just be adding a Cisco VPN interface.
3. `org.pqrs.driver.NoEjectDelay`, `org.pqrs.driver.PCKeyboardHack`, `org.pqrs.driver.KeyRemap4MacBook`. They're hacks. Need I say more?
4. `com.shapeservices.msm.driver.MSMFramebuffer`, `com.shapeservices.msm.driver.MSMVideoDevice`. iDisplay is unlikely to be related, but it might be!

If all else fails, submit a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: My node.js code is doing nothing network related at all.  It's running a modified CoffeeScript repl using readline (node's readline).